# How to use TOP and ORDER BY on a nested DML inserting the result of an OUTPUT statement inside a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have this stored procedure inserting the rows returned by the OUTPUT statement into a table.
I want to select the TOP 10 ordered rows from that nested DML.
I have a TSQL book that tells me you can't use ORDER BY with TOP and that if you want to do it you have to use a CTE.

The thing is I don't know how to do both, creating a CTE within a stored procedure and have a nested DML call it, and if there's a better way to do it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetPlaces
    @UserCity NVARCHAR(100)
    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO dbo.PlaceAudit(
      [PlaceId],
      [Name],
      [Latitude],
      [Longitude]
    )
      SELECT TOP(10)
        [PlaceId],
        [Name],
        [Latitude],
        [Longitude]
      FROM (UPDATE [P]

            SET
              [Name] = N'Test'

            OUTPUT
              INSERTED.[PlaceId],
              INSERTED.[Name],
              INSERTED.[Latitude],
              INSERTED.[Longitude]

           FROM [Place] AS [P]

           JOIN [Timezone] AS [TZ]
             ON [TZ].[TimezoneId] = [P].[TimezoneId]
           JOIN [Address] AS [A]
             ON [P].[PlaceId] = [A].[PlaceId]

           WHERE [A].City = @UserCity
      
      ) AS NDML -- End of nested DML

      ORDER BY P.Name -- or Name

      END
```

I tried to add the ORDER BY clause outside of the nested DML as recommended in the book, but it fails with this error:

> The ORDER BY clause is not allowed when the FROM clause contains a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.

And the TOP methods returns this error:

> The TOP or OFFSET clause is not allowed when the FROM clause contains a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.

**EDIT**

Following @Charlieface's technique, I came to this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spTestForList
  @UserCity NVARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE P

  SET
    [IsOpen] = OpenTimeResult;

OUTPUT
  INSERTED.PlaceId,
  INSERTED.[Name],
  INSERTED.Latitude,
  INSERTED.Longitude
  INSERTED.OpenTimeResult
INTO dbo.PlaceAudit(
  PlaceId,
  [Name],
  Latitude,
  Longitude,
  IsOpen
)

FROM (

  SELECT TOP (10) P.*, OpenTimeCalc.OpenPlace AS OpenTimeResult

  FROM Place AS P
  
  JOIN dbo.Timezone AS TZ
    ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
  JOIN Address AS A
    ON P.PlaceId = A.PlaceId

  CROSS APPLY (
    -- Some timezone calculation AS LocalTime
  ) AS [DT]
  
  JOIN [DayOfTheWeek] AS [DOW]
    ON [DOW].[Name] = [DT].[LocalWeekdayName]

  -- select Place where its local datetime is between its open and closed hours,
    -- for the day returned from the local datetime
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT *
          FROM [StoreHour] AS [SH]
            WHERE [SH].[PlaceId] = [P].[PlaceId]
            AND [SH].[DayOfTheWeekId] = [DOW].[DayOfTheWeekId] 
            AND (DT.LocalTime BETWEEN SH.OpenHour AND SH.CloseHour)
      ) THEN 1 -- IsOpen = TRUE
        ELSE 0 -- IsOpen = FALSE
        END
        AS [OpenPlace] -- END, case AS Alias
  ) AS [OpenTimeCalc]


  WHERE A.City = @UserCity
  ORDER BY P.PlaceId

) AS P;

END
```

It works, however, I get an error I don't know how to solve: "`The column reference "inserted.OpenTimeResult" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.` "

But it is being modified since it is in the `SET` part of the `UPDATE`.
How could I solve it ?

Comment: Insert the output into a temp table, then do whatever you need from the temp table.

Comment: You mean run the `INSERT` and when it is in the temp table, then I use `TOP` and `ORDER BY` on that temp table ? If that's the case, that could be a good idea but is there a way to do it at once within the stored procedure ?

Comment: No, the temptable is the way to do it, and i hint that whatever you're trying to do, maybe you shouldn't :) Why do you want to log partial result of an update anyway

Comment: Why did you write like this? You want to UPDATE a table, sort it by name and SAVE 10 in the new table

Comment: @siggemannen I know what you mean. Should I instead take 10 and THEN update them ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't make any modifications to an `INSERT` with a nested `OUTPUT` DML statement. It has to be a straight `INSERT...SELECT`. Unfortunately this does not appear to be documented. Using a CTE does not help, it's simply disallowed whatever you do.

You need to just filter your results once you have them in a table variable first.

- Also don't quote names with `[]` unless you need to, it's really annoying.

```sql
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (
    PlaceId int,
    Name varchar(100),
    Latitude decimal(38,18),
    Longitude decimal(38,18)
  );

UPDATE P
SET
    Name = N'Test'

  OUTPUT
    INSERTED.PlaceId,
    INSERTED.Name,
    INSERTED.Latitude,
    INSERTED.Longitude
  INTO @tmp (
    PlaceId,
    Name,
    Latitude,
    Longitude
  )

FROM Place AS P
JOIN Timezone AS TZ
  ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
JOIN Address AS A
  ON P.PlaceId = A.PlaceId
WHERE A.City = @UserCity;


INSERT INTO dbo.PlaceAudit (
    PlaceId,
    Name,
    Latitude,
    Longitude
  )
SELECT TOP (10)
  PlaceId,
  Name,
  Latitude,
  Longitude
FROM @tmp
ORDER BY Name;
```

---

Another option which seems to work, is to use a row-number and filter on that in your outer `INSERT`.

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.PlaceAudit (
    PlaceId,
    Name,
    Latitude,
    Longitude
  )
SELECT
  PlaceId,
  Name,
  Latitude,
  Longitude
FROM (

    UPDATE P
    SET
        Name = N'Test'

      OUTPUT
        INSERTED.PlaceId,
        INSERTED.Name,
        INSERTED.Latitude,
        INSERTED.Longitude,
        DELETED.rn

    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.Name)
        FROM Place AS P
    ) AS P
    JOIN Timezone AS TZ
      ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
    JOIN Address AS A
      ON P.PlaceId = A.PlaceId
    WHERE A.City = @UserCity
) AS u
WHERE rn <= 10;
```

I can't say how efficient this though.

---

If you wanted to just update the first 10 rows and output those, then you can do it much easier, by just using a `TOP (10)` directly in the `UPDATE`

```sql
UPDATE P
SET
    Name = N'Test'

  OUTPUT
    INSERTED.PlaceId,
    INSERTED.Name,
    INSERTED.Latitude,
    INSERTED.Longitude
  INTO dbo.PlaceAudit(
    PlaceId,
    Name,
    Latitude,
    Longitude
  )
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (10)
      P.*
    FROM Place AS P
    JOIN Timezone AS TZ
      ON TZ.TimezoneId = P.TimezoneId
    JOIN Address AS A
      ON P.PlaceId = A.PlaceId
    WHERE A.City = @UserCity
    ORDER BY P.PlaceId
) P;
```

Comment: Thank you again Charlie ! and could I put all this code, besides the table declaration, into a stored procedure with the `INSERT SELECT` at the end ?

Comment: Whithin the stored procedure ?

Comment: Wow, i wish i could upvote this answer more than once. I didn't know you can either do a nested insert like that, PLUS, that you can get deleted.rn even though the column is not part of the participating table. Mind blown

Comment: @siggemannen Also relevant https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326842/output-clause-with-window-functions which was why I used `deleted` not `inserted`. I posted that question due to a previous question by this OP which I had trouble with.

Comment: @Charlieface, Interesting, this "smells" to me like being on the border of undefined / buggy behavior. Now, i just gotta find a way to implemented this in all my code :D

Comment: I see, but isn't there a possibility to, within the nested dml, select a `TOP 10` that will be the one being updated ? Something such as a derived `SELECT` within the nested `UPDATE` or `INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT TOP 10 FROM TableName WHERE ... ORDER BY Name` and then in the nested DML: `UPDATE ... FROM TempTableHoldingTheTop10` ? I'm asking this because the `UPDATE` in your code is the main part, but in mine it is in a derived statement so I wanted to know if the `OUTPUT INTO` would work as expected being in a nested statement

Comment: No it's disallowed as I said. The only way to do it is to hack it with a row-number. Unless you mean you only want to *update* 10 rows, yes sure just do `UPDATE TOP (10) ...` Your current logic implies you want to update *all* rows but only receive back 10 from the `OUTPUT`.

Comment: Then it is a mistake in my logic, because I think that if I want to get 10 rows from an update of multiple rows, why not filter on the rows, get the 10 I want and then update them. That makes more sense right ?

Comment: See also new edit. You don't need to select then update, you can update directly. Why use a temp table, that is likely worse from a performance and locking perspective.

Comment: I've seen your edit, the `UPDATE` would then OUTPUT just these 10 updated records right ? That's great ! But how could I `ORDER BY` this ?

Comment: I mean, how to `UPDATE` the relevant rows instead of all of them, if there were a way to `ORDER BY` for the `UPDATE` to know which rows to `UPDATE`, which I doubt it with what you said, because otherwise it would update just any randomly accessed 10 rows right ?

Comment: You can't use `ORDER BY` on the outside, but you can use a derived subquery with an `ORDER BY`, see edit

Comment: I've tested your code @Charlieface and it works ! I made an edit so that you could see it but I'm having an error because of a reference from the derived table to the `OUTPUT` statement, do you know how I could make it work in this case ?

Comment: Please construct a https://dbfiddle.uk showing the issue. I suggest you make a new question if you want help on a different problem: a post is supposed to have a single Q&A not a whole series of questions.

Comment: You're right, here's the link to the new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76230870/trying-to-extract-a-value-from-a-derived-tables-cross-apply-and-use-it-in-the Thank you.