# Trying to extract a value from a derived table's CROSS APPLY, and use it in the outer query's OUTPUT INTO, but getting an error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, output-clause

I have this [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3pxY6q3v) showing the situation, I'm trying to get the value of `OpenTimeCalc.OpenTime` from the derived table and use it in the `OUTPUT INTO` of the outer query like you can see in the stored procedure but I get this error:

> The column reference "inserted.OpenTimeResult" is not allowed because it refers to a base table that is not being modified in this statement.

But it is being modified since it is in the SET part of the UPDATE, and I have no idea on how to solve it. Why is this happening?

You might see a lot of lines in the Seed data line 10 but it's just a timezone mapper, you can fold the Declare statement and it will just be a couple lines.

The error happens on the line 22 of the stored procedure in the `OUTPUT` statement.
I've put `DELETED.OpenTimeResult` but it should be `INSERTED.OpenTimeResult` but then I get the error.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mre]; focusing on ***only*** the part you're struggling with. Then, please include that example in the question, not just a link to an external site.

Comment: You cant do INSERTED and DELETED in same statement like that.  You can do ISNULL(INSERTED.COL, DELETED.COL) as COL  but you can not combine them like that when I have used these anyway.

Comment: I tried, but many places weren't working because of it, I did cut half of the code and then there were bugs everywhere, so I thought I'd post it the way it is so that all the stored proc calculations would work for sure

Comment: @Brad I tried, and it gives me the same error

Comment: I looked closer and that is because that column is not being changed so there is nothing to output DELETED or INSERTED because that column is not being changed in your statements, you cant include something not being changed.

Comment: Right, but I don't get how it's not being changed because the result of `OpenTimeCalc` is changed depending on the result of the `CROSS APPLY`, or is it because if it is set to 1, and the `CROSS APPLY` determines the result of the calculation is 1 as well, then it is considered unchanged ?

Comment: Here's a [cut down example](https://dbfiddle.uk/w7Thr31l) to work from, so you can show what's happening that you don't want, and detail what you do want; as recommended by [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Questions need to be stand alone and not depend on external sites, so while a fiddle is very helpful, the question need to contain the SQL from the fiddle.

Comment: @MatBailie so instead of modifying the property in the `SET` part of the outer query you modify it in the `CROSS APPLY` within the inner query ?

Comment: Your written description makes no sense to me. ***Please*** make an [mre] to demonstrate what you're trying to do, what actually happens, and what you want to happen. I made an [mre] to start you off. If you can't make a working example of your problem, I'd suggest you don't have a problem. (You never ***modify*** OpenTimeResult, because it doesn't even ***exist*** in the table being updated. You ***create*** the expression in the updatable view. If you want the result of the CASE expression, reference the column it's being set into; `INSERTED.IsOpen`...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an undocumented restriction, which I discovered while working on one of your previous questions. [See my question on it on the Database Adminsitrators site.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/326842/output-clause-with-window-functions)

When you refer to the table that is actually being modified in the `UPDATE`, you must use either `inserted` or `deleted`. This is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#scalar_expression).

But in your case you have an updatable derived subquery which you are modifying, so any columns which are calculated, or come from other tables, or for that matter in my case a window function, ***must*** use `deleted` not `inserted`.

It doesn't matter either way, because the column isn't being modified in the `SET` part anyway: you can't modify a calculated column that doesn't actually exist.

To clarify: `inserted` refers to the data *after* the `SET` and `deleted` refers to the *before* the `SET`, but *after* any other calculations on it using joins, `APPLY` or whatever.

Comment: It's not documented that a reference from the table that *is* being modified but is calculated can only use `deleted` not `inserted`

Comment: True, but it's unclear why it works in those cases and not others, because it's undocumented. There's no real reason why a window function shouldn't also work but it doesn't. It appears it's just an artifact of the way the parser/lexer rearranges the query before checking for errors in the references

Comment: Oh I see. So what do you recommend I do in order for it to basically be considered as modified and be able to use it within the `SET` ? Because if I understand, I should use the `DELETED` but then I don't get to use the calculation to modify the outer query's property ?

Comment: No you are misunderstanding. You should just use `deleted` and you will get the full calculation, because `deleted` here refers to after calculations are done, but before the `SET` happens, before any changes are made to the table. If you want to use it the `SET` then just use `P.OpenTimeResult`, as `deleted` and `inserted` are only relevant to the `OUTPUT` clause, not to the `SET`

Comment: Oh now I think I understand. Thank you for your patience. So that means that even though I use `DELETED` in the `OUTPUT`, I will still get the result of the calculation, and even if it’s before the `SET` and the logic seems like I’m going to get a non-calculated result, I’m actually getting the calculated result and it’s just as if I used `INSERTED`, and this confusion is due to the undocumented bug you found there right ?

Comment: Oh and when you said “you can't modify a calculated column that doesn't actually exist.” You meant that this column wasn’t part of the updated table, and therefore that non existant column couldn’t be MODIFIED, I missed the logic behind that, yes that column doesn’t exist so there’s no way it gets processed as part of an update..